# setValueMap in SelectItem do not clear previous items

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

My code defines two SelectItem objects. When selecting an option in the first one, the second one should update its content. After getting data back, I set new LinedHashMap data with setValueMap method, but it does not clear some previous items. This happens after upgrading SmartGwt from v2.2 to v4.0. Is this a bug in this version? May you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it and it's working perfectly fine. I am using `smartgwtpower-4.0p4`. Here I am sharing sample code to validate it again at your end.

Sample code:

```
DynamicForm dynamicForm = new DynamicForm();

final SelectItem item1 = new SelectItem();
LinkedHashMap<String, String> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("animals", "animals");
map1.put("fruits", "fruits");
item1.setValueMap(map1);

final SelectItem item2 = new SelectItem();
item1.addChangedHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.events.ChangedHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.events.ChangedEvent event) {
        if (event.getValue().equals("animals")) {
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            map1.put("dog", "dog");
            map1.put("cat", "cat");
            item2.setValueMap(map1);
        } else if (event.getValue().equals("fruits")) {
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            map1.put("apple", "apple");
            map1.put("mango", "mango");
            item2.setValueMap(map1);
        }
    }
});
dynamicForm.setFields(item1, item2);
```